# Xamarin Android : Scale animation isn't smooth

Tags: android, animation, xamarin, xamarin.android

I made a new Xamarin project and I begun with Android UI implementation. On my screen, I display two textEdit and one imageView. This image is an heart and I've add an animation to beat him. So, this is my XML description of this animation, in the "beat.xml" file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
  <scale
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="100"
      android:fromXScale="0.90"
      android:fromYScale="0.90"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toXScale="0.95"
      android:toYScale="0.95"
      android:repeatMode="reverse"
      android:repeatCount="infinite">
  </scale>
</set>
```

And this is how I start it, in my view Class :

```
[Activity(Label = "Tip", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class TipView : MvxActivity {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            ImageView  heart = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.heartView);
            heart.StartAnimation(AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Drawable.beat));
        }
}
```

The animation is showed but is not smooth at all and not regular ! I disable all other calls and my project so now, it's just a screen with this animation, and is not smooth, even on a very good smartphone (HTC 10, Samsung Galaxy S6). Any tips ?

Thanks in advance,

Cedric

Comment: what is the size of your image in pixels ? I assume it is Android Resource in drawable folder?

Comment: tested on HUAWEI. Seems pretty smooth